# Inequality with $\sum a^5+8\sum ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, tangent-line-method

For every positive real numbers $a,b,c$ for which $a+b+c=3$ we have:
$$a^5+b^5+c^5+8(ab+bc+ca)\ge 27.$$

My ideas is:

We can apply Chebyshev inequality
$$\sum a^5 =\sum a\cdot a^4\ge \frac13 \left(\sum a\right)\left(\sum a^4\right)=\sum a^4.$$
Remains to show that $\sum a^4+8\sum ab \ge 27.$

Comment: This Chebyshev's inequality is new for me.

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality is: if $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\ge 0$, $a_1\le ...\le a_n$ and $b_1\le...\le b_n$: $(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k)\ge\frac1n(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $2(ab+bc+ca)=9-a^2-b^2-c^2$ we have to prove $$a^5+b^5+c^5-4(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge -9$$ Now $$x^5-4x^2\ge -3x\iff x (x - 1)^2 (x^2 + 2 x + 3)\ge 0 \;\forall x\ge 0$$ so $$ a^5+b^5+c^5-4(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge -3(a+b+c)=-9$$ Done

Comment: (This method is the tangent line method )

Comment: I found these descriptions of the tangent line method https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/~makyli/190_2010Sp/Inequality_3.pdf https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v10_n5.pdf